# Sequence point from function call?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

This is yet another sequence-point question, but a rather simple one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int p, int) {
  printf("p: %d\n", p);
}

int g(int* p) {
  *p = 42;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int p = 0;
  f(p, g(&p));
  return 0;
}
```

Is this undefined behaviour? Or does the call to `g(&p)` act as a sequence point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It doesn't invoke *undefined* behavior. It is just *unspecified*, as the order in which the function arguments are evaluated is unspecified in the Standard. So the output could be `0` or `42` depending on the evaluation order decided by your compiler.

Comment: The question also asks whether `g(&p)` acts as a sequence point. There are two sequence points in the evaluation of `g(&p)`: Between the evaluation of `g` and the evaluation of `&p`, and between the evaluation of the “full expressions” `*p = 42;` and the `0` in the `return`. But neither of them order the evaluation of the argument `p` with respect to the evaluation of `g(&p)`.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of the program is unspecified since we don't know the order of evaluation of the function arguments, from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) `1.9` *Program execution paragraph 3*:

> Certain other aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this International Standard **as unspecified (for example, order of evaluation of arguments to a function).** Where possible, this International Standard defines a set of allowable behaviors. [...]

and all side effects from the arguments are sequenced before the function is entered, from section `5.2.2` *Function call paragraph 8*:

> [ Note: The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the argument expressions are all unsequenced relative to one another. **All side effects of argument expression evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered** (see 1.9). —end note ]

As for `C` both points are covered in the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.5.2.2` *Function calls paragraph 10*:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and
>   subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point
>   before the actual call.

So in both `C` and `C++` you can end up with either `f(0,0)` or `f(42,0)`.