# Is a C++ optimizer allowed to move statements across a function call?

Tags: c++, optimization, inline, operator-precedence

**Note:** No multithreading at all here. Just optimized single-threaded code.

A function call [introduces a sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516712/321013). (Apparently.)

Does it follow that a compiler (if the optimizer inlines the function) is *not* allowed to move/intermingle any instructions prior/after with the function's instructions? (As long as it can "proove" no observable effects obviously.)

---

Explanatory background:

Now, there is a [nice article](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/benchmarking-in-c/) wrt. a benchmarking class for C++, where the author stated:

> The code we time won’t be rearranged by the optimizer and will always
>   lie between those start / end calls to now(), so we can guarantee our
>   timing will be valid.

to which I asked how he can be sure, and nick replied:

> You can check the comment in this answer
>   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48884. I quote : *“I would be
>   careful about timing things that are not functions because of
>   optimizations that the compiler is allowed to do. I am not sure about
>   the sequencing requirements and the observable behavior understanding
>   of such a program. With a function call the compiler is not allowed to
>   move statements across the call point (they are sequenced before or
>   after the call).”*
>
> What we do is basically abstract the callable (function, lambda, block
>   of code surrounded by lambda) and have a signle call
>   `callable(factor)` inside the `measure` structure that acts as a
>   barrier (not the barrier in multithreading, I believe I convey the
>   message).

I am quite unsure about this, especially the quote:

> With a function call the compiler is not allowed to
>   move statements across the call point (they are sequenced before or
>   after the call).

Now, I was always under the impression that when an optimizer inlines some function (which may very well be the case in a (simple) benchmark scenario), it is free to rearrange whatever it likes as long as it does not affect observable behavior.

That is, as far as the language / the optimizer are concerned, these two snippets are *exactly* the same:

```
void f() {
  // do stuff / Multiple statements
}

auto start = ...;
f();
auto stop = ...;
```

vs.

```
auto start = ...;
  // do stuff / Multiple statements
auto stop = ...;
```

Comment: The optimizer doesn't "move statements". Statements are part of the program, not of the emitted code. The optimizer typically moves instructions in the compilation output around in a way that does not affect the interpretation of the input program and that hopefully executes faster on the target platform.

Comment: Under as-if rule, the optimizer is allowed to do anything at all, as long as the observable behavior of the resulting program matches one of possible executions of the abstract machine.

Comment: @KerrekSB - corrected wording. I was aware of that.

Comment: What if you make start and stop a volatile ?

Comment: The quote is just wrong. The compiler is free to execute things out of sequence so long as the observable behavior of the program as defined in the standard is unchanged. Sequence points are about what's part of the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: This isn't so much a question of optimizer behaviour but language semantics. The optimizer is allowed to do anything, as long as it follows the _as if_ rule. However, there are certain things in C++ that do not have entirely specified behaviour.

Comment: FWIW you can prevent compiler reordering with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Compile-time_memory_barrier_implementation, which includes the well-known `asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");` statement.  Obviously, inline assembly is not ISO C++, but C++11's `std::atomic_signal_fence` should be equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

> Now, I was always under the impression that when an optimizer inlines
>   some function (which may very well be the case in a (simple) benchmark
>   scenario), it is free to rearrange whatever it likes as long as it
>   does not affect observable behavior.

It absolutely is. The optimizer doesn't even need to inline it for this to occur in theory.

However, timing functions are observable behaviour- specifically, they are I/O on the part of the system. The optimizer cannot know that that I/O will produce the same outcome (it obviously won't) if performed in a different order to other I/O calls, which can include non-obvious things like even memory allocation calls that can invoke syscalls to get their memory.

What this basically means is that by and large, for most function calls, the optimizer can't do a great deal of re-arranging because there's potentially a vast quantity of state involved that it can't reason about.

Furthermore, the optimizer can't really know that re-arranging your function calls will actually make the code run faster, and it will make debugging it harder, so they don't have a great deal of incentive to go screwing around with the program's stated order.

Basically, in theory the optimizer can do this, but in reality it won't because doing so would be a massive undertaking for not a lot of benefit.

You'll only encounter conditions like this if your benchmark is fairly trivial or consists virtually entirely of primitive operations like integer addition- in which case you'll want to check the assembly anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember a GCC example where they tried to benchmark std::vector and the optimiser purportedly messed it up. So while I agree with most everything you say, it wont write it off as purely theoretical. Cheers.

Comment: @MartinBa: You might want to source that one. The optimiser can mess up a benchmark in many, many ways other than the one theorised in the question. And it's not really "messed up". The optimizer is simply pointing out that your benchmark is not representative. Anyways, everybody reading this question (and me) could benefit if you could source that example.

Comment: @Puppy Good point !  The timer should indeed be considered as an IO function.  However this alone doesn't ensure sequencing with the instructions in the body that have no side effect and have not a squenced-before relation the I/O.

Comment: @Christophe: The purpose of my answer was to point out that virtually every function has side effects, from the optimizer's perspective, which makes it incredibly difficult for this to occur.

Comment: Timing is not observable because the standard does not dictate how long it takes to execute anything. Also, the clock can move forwards and backwards arbitrarily. Therefore, you can never prove that this optimization occurred. This makes it legal.

Comment: @usr: That would require that the optimizer understands the precise notion of timing. Programming the optimizer with special knowledge of every single function and syscall is completely impractical.

Comment: To usr's comment and Christophe's comment, I think a timer *should* be treated as I/O.  However, there is nothing in the spec which actually forces a compiler to do so.  In the real world, you can generally expect that a compiler will not mis-optimize a timing, because people get angry at such compilers.  Most compilers will elect *not* to reorder unless they can prove no sys-call could occur.  However, it *is* legal to do the optimization, as usr says.

Comment: We recently had a question here where timing was reordered and a benchmark invalidated. The question was whether this was legal or not. It was but the compiler was crap.

Comment: @Puppy: All Standard Library calls are formally observable. Using a non-standard timer is of course non-standard which means you'll have to check compiler and/or library documentation.

Comment: @usr: My answer clearly states that it is legal. The point that I was making is not only that it is legal, but that in practice it's pretty damn difficult for it to occur.

Comment: @Puppy I agree with 90% of your answer but it also states that timing calls are IO which are illegal to reorder. I'm not sure I agree with that because I don't see why the compiler isn't allowed to have special knowledge about certain IO functions. This should be covered under the as-if rule.

Comment: @Puppy: I would note that should the compiler realizes that your function does not perform I/O it could therefore move the function execution. Memory allocation is (for example) special-cased in LLVM (a pair alloc/dealloc can be elided if the memory is unused), and may not be considered I/O for long... Otherwise, I agree with you, it's doubtful that any compiler would implement such "weird" optimizations; compiler writers are very pragmatic.

Comment: After re-reading this, I think your point about the timing function being I/O is a red herring: The point is not that the optimizer may move start or stop, but that `f()` being a simple non-I/O loop could be "legitimately" moved before start or after stop, because the optimizer can prove that it has no side effects accessible to the two timing calls. (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041519/benchmarking-code-reordering-volatile -- though there's nothing definite there either.)

Answer (score 6):

Your concern is perfectly valid, the optimizer is allowed to move anything past a function call if it can prove that this does not change observable behavior (other than runtime, that is).

The point about using a function to stop the optimizer from doing things is **not to tell the optimizer about the function**. That is, the function must not be inlined, and it must not be included in the same compilation unit. Since optimizers are generally a compiler feature, moving the function definition to a different compilation unit deprives the optimizer of the information necessary to prove anything about the function, and consequently stops it from moving anything across the function call.

Beware that this assumes that there is no linker doing global analysis for optimization. If it does, it can still skrew you.

Comment: +1 Pragmatic and effective.  The global optimization at linking could further be prevented by using dynamic linking.

Comment: @cmaster: There are pragmas/attributes specific to compilers to prevent inlining (gcc's `noinline` for example).

Comment: @MatthieuM. That may not stop the optimizer from doing its work. If the function is not inlined, nothing may be moved into/out of the function, that is true. However, stuff may still be moved across its call.

Comment: @cmaster: Agreed, I was just giving a surefire way to avoid inlining; but it's only half the battle.

Answer (score 6):

What the comment you quoted has not considered is that sequence points are not primarily about order of execution (although they do constrain it, they don't act as full barriers), but rather about values of expressions.

C++11 actually gets rid of the "sequence point" terminology completely, and instead discussed ordering of "value computation" and "side effects".

To illustrate, the following code exhibits undefined behavior because it doesn't respect ordering:

```
int a = 5;
int x = a++ + a;
```

This version is well-defined:

```
int a = 5;
a++;
int x = a + a;
```

When the sequence point / ordering of side effects and value computations guarantees us, is that the `a` used in `x = a + a` is `6`, not `5`.  So the compiler cannot rewrite it to:

```
int a = 5;
int x = a + a;
a++;
```

However, it's perfectly legal to rewrite it as:

```
int a = 5;
int x = (a+1) + (a+1);
a++;
```

The order of execution between assigning `x` and assigning `a` isn't constrained, because neither of them is `volatile` or `atomic<T>` and they aren't externally visible side effects.

Comment: You explain very well the relative sequencing constaints that replace the somewhat abstract "sequence point". Maybe it's worth to add that making `a` or `x` volatile doesn't ensure sequencing of other computations that don't rely/don't influence  these values.

Answer (score 2):

The standard leaves definitively free room for the optimizer to sequence operations across the boundary of a function:

> 1.9/15 Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or
>   after the execution of the body of the called function is
>   indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called
>   function.

as long as the *as-if* rule is respectd:

> **1.9/5** A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall produce the same observable behavior as one of the possible
>   executions of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with
>   the same program and the same input.

The practice of leaving the optimizer in the blind as suggested by ***cmaster*** is in general very effective.  By the way, the global optimization issue at linking can also be circumvented using dynamic linking of the benchmarked function.

There is, however, another a **hard sequencing constraint** that can be used to achieve the same purpose, even within the same compilation unit:

> **1.9/15** When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), **every value computation and side effect associated with any
>   argument expression**, or with the postfix expression designating the
>   called function, **is sequenced before** execution of every expression
>   or statement in the **body of the called function**.

So you may use safely an expression like:

```
 my_timer_off(stop, f( my_timer_on(start) ) );
```

This "functional" writing ensures that:

- `my_timer_on()` is evaluated before any statement of `f()` is executed,
- `f()` is called before the body of `my_timer_off()` is executed
- thus ensuring the sequence timer-on / f / timer-off (the my_timer_xx would take the start/stop by value).

Of course, this assumes that the signature of the benchmarked function `f()` can be changed to allow the expression above.

Comment: There's a much simpler way to achieve a sequenced-before relationship: "Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value
computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated."

Comment: Writing the code in a certain syntactic way does not "cheat" the as-if rule. Any optimization that a human can do the compiler can do as well.

Comment: @usr it's not a question of syntactic cheating.  It's exploiting a semantic guarantee that is given by the standard.

Comment: The rule you've cited concerns expressions such as `(a + b) * f()`, where it isn't specified whether `a + b` is computed before or after `f()` is called, or part before and part after.