# Why sum1 = 46 and sum2 = 48

Tags: c, function, pointers, undefined-behavior

In the code mentioned below sum1 variable is getting 46 as the answer when operators precedence left to right.But in sum2 answer is getting as 48 and it's precedence is right to left. Why those answers are getting different.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *k){
    *k+=4;
    return 3 * (*k)-1;
}

void main() {
    int i = 10, j = 10, sum1, sum2;
    sum1 = (i / 2) + func(&i);
    sum2 = func(&j)+(j/2);
    printf("%d\n",sum1);
    printf("%d",sum2);
}
```

Comment: This is known as [unspecified behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984). The compiler is free to evaluate the operands to `+` in any order it pleases. So it can call the function first, or do the division first.

Comment: This question is relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516510/sequence-point-from-function-call

Comment: This question is also relevant, even more so than the one above:  [**In C99, is f()+g() undefined or merely unspecified?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951017/in-c99-is-fg-undefined-or-merely-unspecified)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Right, it's definitely unspecified behavior. Whether or not it's undefined is debatable, but moot, given that code with unspecified behavior is not useful (it can easily be refactored so that the behavior is fully specified).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because the order of evaluation of operands in an additive operator is unspecified and **such evaluations of operands are unsequenced**.

Pay attention to that within the assignment expression the variables `i` and `j` are being changed and these changes are not sequenced. Either `i / 2` or `j / 2`  can be evaluated before the function call or vice versa.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207008/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow-why-sum1-46-and-sum2-48).

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `(i / 2) + func(&i)`, the compiler (or the C implementation generally) is free to evaluate either `i / 2` first or `func(&i)` first. Similarly, in `func(&j) + (j/2)`, the compiler is free to evaluate `func(&j)` or `j/2` first.

Precedence is irrelevant. Precedence tells us how an expression is structured, but it does not fully determine the order in which it is evaluated. Precedence tells us that, in `a * b + c * d`, the structure must be `(a * b) + (c * d)`. In `a + b + c`, precedence, in the form of left-to-right association for `+`, tells us the structure must be `(a + b) + c`. It does not tell that `a` must be evaluated before `c`. For example, in `a() + b() + c()`, the structure is `(a() + b()) + c()`, but the compiler may call the functions in any order, holding their results in temporary registers if needed, and then add the results.

In `func(&j)+(j/2)`, there is no right-to-left precedence or association. No rule in the C standard says `j/2` must be evaluated before `func(&j)`.

A compiler might tend to evaluate subexpressions from left to right, in the absence of other constraints. However, various factors may alter that. For example, if one subexpression appears multiple times, the compiler might evaluate it early and retain its value for reuse. Essentially, the compiler builds a tree structure describing the expressions it needs to evaluate and then seeks optimal ways to evaluate them. It does not necessarily proceed left to right, and you cannot rely on any particular evaluation order.

### Questions about Sequencing

The C standard has a rule, in C 2018 6.5 2, that says if a modification to an object, as occurs to `i` in the statement `*k+=4;`, is unsequenced relative to a value computation using the same object, as occurs for `i` in `i / 2`, then the behavior is undefined. However, this problem does not occur in this code because the modification and the value computation are indeterminately sequenced, not unsequenced: 6.5.2.2 10 says “… Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to execution of the called function.” C 5.1.2.3 3 says “… Evaluations A and B are *indeterminately sequenced* when A is sequenced either before or after B, but it is unspecified which…”

Answer (score -1):

The & preceding the variable name (&i or &j) is sending a pointer meaning that any changes to the variable are saved.  In this case, the func call takes a variable and adds 4 to it then returns some value based on that variable.  The function still changed the variable's value and since the equation is being processed left to right, each subsequent use of the variable has that change reflected.

```
sum1 = (i/2) +func(&i) (where i = 10)
--> sum1 = 5 + func(&i)
--> sum1 = 5 + 41 (and now i = 14)

sum2 = func(&j) + (j/2) (where j = 10)
--> sum2 = 41 + (j/2) (and now j = 14)
--> sum2 = 41 + 7
```